# Peer-to-Peer decentralized network - message to all peers

Tags: c#, .net, http, networking, p2p

I need to create **a file-sharing peer-to-peer network** (without a central server).

I read a lot of information on the topic. The requirement is to make sure every peer in the network keeps a full list of the other peers and a full list of all the files on the network.

I know it's not the best way to do it, but it's a requirement so ... Another (in my opinion weird) requirement is that the communication between the peers should be implemented with the HTTP protocol and JSON-serialized.

This means every peer will act as a web-server and will also have a way to connect to every other peer.

So I want to know a good way to deliver a message from one peer to all others without having a single peer to connect directly to the others (too many connections).

I've been looking for a way to somehow route the message a few levels so the traffic will be somewhat distributed. As I know and can connect to any peer on the network I can effectively construct a route before the message is sent and then tell some peers to reroute it. But how do I figure out the best route? And what happens if there's a bugged peer which can't reroute the message?

**EDIT:** I'm sorry if I didn't make it clear. The message should be received by ALL peers on the network, not just one target.

**EDIT 2:** You can think of what I want to do as a network of web servers. They should be able to hold data distributed (not part of the question) but every one of them needs to know what resources are available on the network (a hash-table). A client can upload stuff on one of the servers (doesn't matter which one). When that happens ALL others need to know of this change to update their hash-tables. The same applies if a new server joins the network. My question is how to propagate this message without having a single server to connect to all the others, which clearly will generate a lot of traffic on a single server.

Comment: Is it actually a requirement for every node to know about all the others? If so, why? Most p2p systems only know about part of the network, and they then have to ask other nodes to help discover the node they want (e.g. a node containing a file having a name matching a search string).

Comment: Yes, it's a requirement. I know it's weird.

Comment: If you don't make each node connect to every other node on the network, then what happens when a node joins (or leaves) the network, before that message has had time to propagate and all nodes update their local nodelists? When you have nodes concurrently joining and leaving the network (particularly at high rates) I can see that causing issues.

Comment: It's not a problem if at a point of time the node list contains a node that is offline. It's also the HTTP problem, because I can't keep a constantly open connection to the nodes and some kind of ping mechanism must be implemented to periodically clear offline nodes.

Comment: "I've been looking for a way to somehow route the message a few levels so the traffic will be somewhat distributed" - by this, do you mean that traffic will hop between several nodes, even though every node could just contact its target directly?

Comment: @halfer Yes, isn't that better than for example one node to connect to all others if they are a lot? For example if you have 1001 nodes the first way the first node will send a message 1000 times. Wouldn't it be better to send the message to 40 nodes and each one to deliver it to another 25 or something like that? With 2 hops you get 10*10*10 which will mean that every node will have to send just 10 messages. There's no target. All nodes should get the message.

Comment: Does that need to scale (it will not) and handle end users (it will not - thanks to NAT - at least without a lot of prorgamming and realying super-nodes)?

Comment: @stormbreaker - Ah, gotcha; I missed the point about sending to all ('from one peer to all others'). In that case, yes, your way is good. You will need to develop an algorithm to determine how nodes know who they should send to, and which nodes will receive the same file from others.

Comment: Such a network is clearly not scalable, but I assume you know that already.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Yeah, I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your question divided in two components:

**No central server**

Popular p2p entities these days are botnets, which have C&C servers, and do use HTTP too. They tend to exploit DNS by using some kind of an algorithm to generate domain names. You need something to seed/bootstrap the process, otherwise the p2p platform won't start. Evolution can be done by propagation, that is, peers can get an initial list from a central location, then build up the DHT as they learn more from querying other peers (i.e. get more responses back).

For a p2p network without a central server, you can do a local network scan or use an implementation of zeroconf protocols such as [SSPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol). The restriction here is that you cannot grow beyond your local network. For instance, say you'd like to multicast beyond your LAN, what IPs/ranges are you going to try reach?

**Messaging all peers**

There is no guarantee for this to succeed, because you do not know at a given point in time which peers are active, and no single peer has a full copy of the DHT. Flooding is generally the way this is accomplished. You can adopt the [query flooding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_flooding) strategy, but don't expect an answer back. You can use the same strategy for searches, where you actually want the answer back. In case you want to reach say only past 5 levels, you simply include a counter with the hash/id, that the peers decrement before propagating the message on, and stop when the counter reaches 0.

A big hurdle with this project is NAT. So, not only peers will need to know each others external IP and port. If you are within a LAN this is not much of a problem.

Comment: Yes, I'll use some initial list of peers to get access to the network. Don't worry about NAT. I will make sure that clients can act as peers only if they can listen to a port for the outside world (if there's no NAT or upnp can open a port). Also the goal is to be able to hold the full list on every peer. But to do that, when there are changes I need to propagate them on all the peers. I will look into the query flooding but the thing is I won't have open persistent connections to other nodes (as it's HTTP) and I will be able to connect to any peer I want.

Comment: I updated my question with some more explanations. Thanks for helping

Comment: It's okay if you don't have persistent connections. A client cannot possibly keep open connections to all peers. Each peer can lazily/periodically check its list of peers if they are still alive. Query flooding is a far more effective way of dealing with this though, because each peer gets to query a subset of the peers, where as, if a single peer had to account for everyone, it would be horribly slow.

Comment: In this query flooding strategy does the peer sending the message tell the others how should be the message routed? I mean if the one sending the message should tell the next to who to send the message? I see no other way to define the `neighbours` of a peer, because all of them will be reachable.

Comment: No, query flooding doesn't include routing information. However, kazaa, for instance, would use connection measures (bandwidth, latency) to determine who the super-peers were and would route the message to them first, then to the lesser peers. Even when downloading a file, the protocol would pick up the super-peers first as well. That being said, you do need to decidd what the neighborhood of a peer is. Is it the whole world or just a subset of peers?

Comment: That's kind of the question. Every peer can connect to any other, so how do I decide which will be neighbors. Maybe the closest servers in the sorted server-list? But then the question will be how many of them?

Comment: Well, I don't think you need worry much about the kind of peers you have  in the peer-list of a given peer. If you only keep a subset of all the peers, say a configurable setting of about 100, that should be enough. If you keep everything, then definitely I'd rate them. Trace route length, bandwidth tests, response time.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, I'll research the topic further.